# Static files in GAE Cloud

Tags: google-app-engine

When an application is deployed in GAE cloud (Appspot.com); Is there a way to update or modify the static files on the src/main/webapps folder? For example the HTML and JSP files?

- Either upload a modified HTML and JSP without redeploying the whole application?

Much like what we can do with Apache Tomcat, where we can modify the contents of the deployed app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no other way short of redeploying the entire app. App Engine runs in a sandbox, and write file access is one of the things disallowed by the security manager.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, "Writing to local files is not supported in App Engine" http://goo.gl/kxNM5